# Replace a value in a comma separated string in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

I'm using a SQL Server 2014 database and I have a column that contains comma-separated values such as:

```
1,2,3
4,5
3,6,2
4,2,8
2
```

What I need to do is to replace the number 2 with the number 3 (string values) in each record and not duplicate the 3 if possible. I'm not sure that this can be done unless I use a function and I'm not sure how to do it in a function.

I think I need to split a string into a table and then loop the values and put it back together with the new value. Is there an easier way? Any help is appreciated.

Expect output would therefore be:

```
1,3
4,5
3,6
4,3,8
3
```

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separate items, it will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Could you post some expected outputs?

Comment: instead of 1,2,3     I need 1,3   and instead of 3,6,2  just 3,6 and 4,2,8 becomes 4,3,8  and the last 2 becomes 3.  The number three can change based upon the situation-  it may be a 4 or an 8- etc

Comment: @jarlh I don't completely agree with that; as in the "never, ever store". There are plenty of ways of extracted delimited values in SQL Server. I still don't recommend it, but there are cases where you may be forced to do so, much like there are times when you don't follow 3NF/5NF.

Comment: the comma separated values are used to check values in a check combo box for that record and has worked well for years.  When a person clicks on the combo box the selected values are shown checked

Comment: So you need to read about database normalisation and why you should use it. It may have worked for years. It will not have worked as well as it *could* or *should*. Storing data like this makes it harder to use, at a minimum.

Answer (score 3):

While it is possible, ***I do not encourage this***:

```
DECLARE @old AS VARCHAR(3) = '2';
DECLARE @new AS VARCHAR(3) = '3';

WITH opdata(csv) AS (
    SELECT '1,22,3' UNION ALL
    SELECT '1,2,3'  UNION ALL
    SELECT '4,5'    UNION ALL
    SELECT '3,6,2'  UNION ALL
    SELECT '4,2,8'  UNION ALL
    SELECT '2'
), cte1 AS (
    SELECT
        csv,
        CASE
        WHEN ',' + csv + ',' LIKE '%,' + @old + ',%' THEN
            CASE
            WHEN ',' + csv + ',' LIKE '%,' + @new + ',%' THEN REPLACE(',' + csv + ',', ',' + @old + ',', ',')              -- new already present so just delete old
            ELSE                                              REPLACE(',' + csv + ',', ',' + @old + ',', ',' + @new + ',') -- replace old with new
            END
        ELSE ',' + csv + ','
        END AS tmp
    FROM opdata
)
SELECT
    csv,
    STUFF(STUFF(tmp, 1, 1, ''), LEN(tmp) - 1, 1, '') AS res
FROM cte1
```

Result:

```
csv    | res
-------+-------
1,22,3 | 1,22,3
1,2,3  | 1,3
4,5    | 4,5
3,6,2  | 3,6
4,2,8  | 4,3,8
2      | 3
```

Note that the plethora of `',...,'` is required to avoid replacing values such as 22. If you are using SQL Server 2017 you can ditch the extra CTE + STUFF and use `TRIM(',' FROM ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to perform particularly well, however:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES ('1,2,3'),
                 ('4,5'),
                 ('3,6,2'),
                 ('4,2,8'),
                 ('2')) V(DS))
SELECT CASE WHEN DS LIKE '%3%' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(DS,'2,',''),',2','')
            WHEN DS LIKE '%2%' THEN REPLACE(DS,'2','3')
            ELSE DS
       END
FROM CTE;
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try

Answer (score 1):

May be you are looking something like this.

```
SELECT REPLACE(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('2', '1,2,3') > 0 THEN REPLACE('1,2,3', '2','') ELSE REPLACE('1,2,3', '2','3') END, ',,',',')
```

I have taken a hard coded value for demonstration. You can replace`'1,2,3'` with column name in the table.

Comment: I like that-- looks interesting and I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

To update:

```
DECLARE @was nvarchar(2) = 2,
        @willbe nvarchar(2) = 3,
        @d nvarchar(1) = ','

UPDATE strings
SET string = REVERSE(
                    STUFF(
                        REVERSE(
                            STUFF(
                                CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(@d+@willbe+@d,@d+string+@d) > 0 
                                    THEN REPLACE(@d+string+@d,@d+@was+@d,@d) 
                                    ELSE REPLACE(@d+string+@d,@d+@was+@d,@d+@willbe+@d) 
                                        END,1,1,'')
                                    ),1,1,''))
```

Output:

```
1,3
4,5
3,6
4,3,8
3
```